# How to morph or cast an eloquent model to one of its child based on the value of a parent type relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have a `room` table with a foreign key `room_type_id` to a `room_type` table.

I have the corresponding models in Laravel as well as some child classes for the different rooms:

```php
class RoomType extends Model
{
    //
}

class Room extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['roomType'];

    public function roomType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('RoomType', 'room_type_id');
    }
}

class Bedroom extends Room
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('type', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->whereHas('roomType', function ($query) {
                $query->where('code', 'like', 'BEDROOM');
            });
        });
    }
}

class Kitchen extends Room
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('type', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->whereHas('roomType', function ($query) {
                $query->where('code', 'like', 'KITCHEN');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is when querying for a `room`, have the child (`bedroom` or `kitchen`) be returned based on the type.

What I'm doing right now:

```php
$results = Room::where('...')->get();
foreach ($results as $key => $record) {
    switch ($record->roomType->code) {
        case 'BEDROOM':
            $results{$key} = (new Bedroom)
            ->newInstance([], true)
            ->setRawAttributes($record->getAttributes());
            break;
        case 'KITCHEN':
            $results{$key} = (new Kitchen)
            ->newInstance([], true)
            ->setRawAttributes($record->getAttributes());
            break;
    }
}
// returns a Collection of `Bedroom` and `Kitchen` models
```

I don't like that I need to create each and every model with `setRawAttributes()`, plus I would need to add all the eager loaded relations back in, plus I loose the original attributes should I need them, well, it just looks wrong the way I do it.

What I would like to achieve is for the same query to return a Collection of child models based on its roomType->code relation value:

```php
$results = Room::where('...')->get();
// returns a Collection of `Room` (shocker!)
// i want a Collection of `Bedroom` and 'Kitchen`
```

I thought I could use polymorphism somehow and morphMap but I can't get it to work, I'm not in a typical polymorphic relationship.

Any help or hint would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: I don't think you should have 2 models (actually, 3 models) for a single table. This is what is making things difficult for you. Why don't you just use the `Room` model and check the `room_type_id` when you need to know if it's a kitchen or a bedroom? Maybe make 2 constants for the 2 room type ids like: `const KITCHEN = 1;`. Then you can check more easily the type without having to query they room type model.

Comment: I'm not sure we shouldn't use class inheritance on a single table. There are use cases, but this is another debate. My question is not about this. My project needs different models for different room types, I'm using an automated api library to interpret these models as resources. Thank you for your good advise, I'll think about it in another context. But the question is still open.

Comment: OK then, maybe overriding the `newInstance` method in the `Room` model could help. You could make a different instance (`Kitchen` or `Bedroom`) based on `$attributes['room_type_id']`.